# Swift3 Fade in/Fade out or Smooth transition UIImageView animationImages

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimageview, uiviewanimationtransition

I am trying to do an images slideshow

What is the best way do add a smooth transition for animationImages in a UIImageView (Swift3)

here my code for the slideshow :

```
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.animationImages = activeImages
                imageView.clipsToBounds = true
                imageView.animationDuration = (1.0 * Double(activeImages.count))
                imageView.animationRepeatCount = Int.max
                imageView.startAnimating()
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIVIew.animate` blocks and two `UIImageViews` for transitions, they are commonly used and produce very clean code.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
               delay: 0,
               options: .curveEaseInOut, //just an example, check UIViewAnimationOptions
               animations: {
      self.image1.alpha = 0
      self.image2.alpha = 1
})
```

Comment: I would like a slideshow that is repeat indefinitely with an array of 20 pictures, I thought that UIVIew.animate is better for temporarily animation, isn't it ?

Comment: This response is not what the user would like to solve here